# Fullcalendar not allow multiple event per day

Tags: fullcalendar

Working with fullcalendar on month view, i need to allow user to create max 1 event per day. If he/she try to add more, error will be show.

I'm aweare there is `eventOverlap` and `eventLimit`, i try to use both but none seems to work:

I set:

```
eventOverlap:false
```

and even try:

```
eventLimit: true, 


views: { month: { eventLimit: 1 } },
```

Just to be clear, the view i'm talking about is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it! 
In a month view with `select: true` you should use:

`selectOverlap` and set it to `false`.

Comment: This is not working for me at all, i can still create many events in one day